# Creating a view's model when I only know the view in backbone?

Tags: backbone.js, view, model

I have an access to FooView.

and I want to create FooView.model instance.

I tried `fooModel = new FooView.model()` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Views in backbone don't have models!

FooView is probably a view class, based on the name (a common convention in Javascript is to start Classes with an uppercase letter and variable with a lowercase letter)... so I assume that somewhere, you have a:

```
 var myView = new FooView();
```

Correct?

If you do that, you'll see that myView.model is undefined. You can see it at the creation time:

```
var myView = new FooView({model: myModel});
```

Then, myView.model should be equal to myModel.

Under the hood, the view's model property is just a backreference to an existing model, the view will not create new model instances automatically or anything, really. You could actually have views without models or store your model's backreference in myView.coolName. Putting the model storing the info necessary for the view to do its job in 'model' is just a convention.

So, in summary what you should probably be doing is something more along the lines of:

```
 //FooModel is another class extending from Backbone.Model
 var myModel = new FooModel({fooStuff: "value", otherFooStuff: "something else"...});
 var myView = new FooView({model: myModel});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the input. I want to store the class of the model in view. and use it at runtime. var myModel = new FooView.Model({foostuff: "valus"}); something like this..

Comment: Why do you want to store a Model class in a View class? That would be very unusual... that being said, you can always store whatever in classes. So... if you do: FooView.Model = Backbone.Model.extend({...}) then in the FooView class, you'll find a property .Model that you can 'new' with new FooView.Model({foostuff: "valus"}). But once again, that would be very confusing for anyone but you as it's a strange place to store a Model class.